# Apigee OPDK, unable to make an API call

Tags: api, cloud, apigee

I installed OPDK on my local machine & deployed an Apigee API Bundle on the instance. Next when I try to make an API call from Postman, I am NOT able to get a response instead I get,

This seems to be like an "error connecting to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59002/v1/proxytemplate?w=1235. The response status was 0."
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.

On my Console I also see this error:

Error while Fetching Object
could not resolve scope myOrg.prod

(myOrg is my org name).

Incidentally this same api bundle works when I deploy it on the cloud. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening on OPDK?

With Regards
-S

Comment: It is best to work directly with Apigee Support on this issue. Please enter a ticket using your Support Portal account and someone will get right back to you. If you don't have an account or know how to set one up, contact help@apigee.com and we will send you the details.

Answer (score 0):

> > Error while Fetching Object could not resolve scope myOrg.prod

This error occurs because you did not enable Analytics for that org / env.